# Sending POST request with array in body with HTTParty

Tags: ruby, rest, httparty

I'm trying to create new subscribers over the Buttondown API.

[Docs here](https://api.buttondown.email/v1/schema#operation/subscribers_create).

The api expects the following body:

```
{
  "email": "string",
  "notes": "string",
  "referrer_url": "string",
  "tags": [
    "string"
  ]
}
```

The email field is required and all others are optional.

I can succesfully create a new subscriber. However, I am unable to add any tags.

I have already created a tag named 'marketing' and have confirmed it exists.

I create a new subscriber like so:

```
  body = {
    'email': params[:email],
    'referrer_url': params[:referer],
    'tags': ['marketing']
  }

  res = HTTParty.post(
          'https://api.buttondown.email/v1/subscribers', 
          body: body,
          headers: headers
        )
```

I expect the above to create a new subscriber with the *marketing* tag. But, looking at the response, the tag hasn't made it to the record.

```
{
  "creation_date"=>"2020-04-22T16:06:22.114523Z",
   "email"=>"user@example.com",
   "id"=>"********-****-****-****-************",
   "notes"=>"",
   "referrer_url"=>"http://localhost:3000/",
   "metadata"=>{},
   "secondary_id"=>18,
   "subscriber_type"=>"regular",
   "source"=>"api",
   "tags"=>[],
   "utm_campaign"=>"",
   "utm_medium"=>"",
   "utm_source"=>""
}
```

Am I sending the array correctly? Am I making my POST request correctly? Is there anything in the Buttondown docs to suggest I'm not sending the tag correctly?

Comment: Did you set `'Content-Type' => 'application/json'` in the headers? Did you try to call `body.to_json`?

Answer (score -1):

As [spickermann](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2483313/spickermann) says it the comment, I needed to set the content type in the headers and call `to_json` on the body.

```
    headers = {
      ...
      'Content-Type' => 'application/json'
    }
```

```
    res = HTTParty.post(
      'https://api.buttondown.email/v1/subscribers', 
      body: body.to_json,
      headers: headers
    )
```